# JBoss, Maven and JSF - Runtime compilation (xhtml files)

Tags: maven, jsf, jboss, compilation

I've the following doubt:

I'm developing a JSF project, with Maven 3.0.5 and Jboss 7.0.1. The structure of the project is like this:

- project-core-internals

  - project-data-access-api
  - project-data-access-spi
  - project-services-api
  - project-services-spi
- project-ear

  - (This project hasn't any file within but has a pom.xml file).
- main-project

  - (This project contains all projects inside)
- project-web

  - src

    - main

      - webapp

        - XHTML files
      - java-objects

        - java Files

For compile the project and view the changes in the navigator, i should follow the next steps:

- Start JBoss 7.0.1 Server
- Right click in main-project (only in this project) -> Run -> Maven build (with goals: "clean install jboss-as:deploy").
- When the Eclipse finished the compilation, i already see the changes in the navigator. Now, the problem is that time compilation is long! (3 minutes approximately).

So, following this way every time I want to see changes, mmmmmm.. I guess the project will be finished in 2099

At least, i want to see the changes of the xhtml modified files instantly. How could do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. use m2e plugin instead of directly invoke maven
2. make all your modules SNAPSHOT: compiling main project will also compile  SNAPSHOT modules/dependencies
3. use a server adapter for deploy: enables xhtml hot deploy
4. run server in debug mode: enables to modify and "soft-compile" methods body without full redeploy (still fighting with this one...)

this is what i do:

1. project -> clean... -> check only main project -> build only selected projects -> ok
2. window -> show view -> other... -> servers
3. right-click on server (i use glassfish, but it's the same) -> debug
4. wait for server to start (check progress and log)
5. right-click on server -> add and remove... -> choose your main project -> ok
6. wait for deploy -> check progress ("Deploying app ....")
7. edit some xhtml -> ctrl+s -> check progress ("Deploying app ....")
8. check result in browser
9. add a new class (or add a method, or do some edit that requires recompile)
10. project -> clean... -> check only main project -> build only selected projects -> ok
11. wait for re-deploy -> check progress ("Deploying app ....")

additional tips:

- uncheck project -> build automatically
- remove your app from server before stop (at least in glassfish, otherwise it will be deployed and redeployed on start, taking double time)
- check in your server page (double click server) -> publishing -> automatically publish when a resource change
- if your build fails (there's some java error) remove your app from server, correct the error, clean-build, re-add to server
- if you stopped server and not removed app, delete app deploy folder before restart (in glassfish: right click on server -> domain directory -> delete eclipseApps folder

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your reply, but i tried that and not successful, not in my case :(

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply.

Finally, i have taken the easiest way for do that.. I discovered a tmp directory in jboss, and inside of, all before deployments. If I modify the xhtml files of the last deployment, the changes are visible in the navigator instantly.

So, my solution (not a clear solution at all, but i can't spent more time in this) is:

I created a bat with the following code:

```
cd C:\Users\My-User\Documents\My-project-dir-name\Web-project-dir-name\webapp

XCopy "firstXHTMLFolder\*.*" "C:\Program Files (x86)\jboss-as-7.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment68e17477ffe883dd\deployment.war-4e5da14584259482\firstXHTMLFolder\*.*" /s /y

XCopy "twoXHTMLFolder\*.*" "C:\Program Files (x86)\jboss-as-7.0.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\deployment68e17477ffe883dd\deployment.war-4e5da14584259482\twoXHTMLFolder\*.*" /s /y

cd C:\Users\Emmanuel\Desktop
```

I only wanted to see the XHTML changes in the navigator instantly, so this solution is valid for me. Anyway, if you want to see the .java changes, this solution will not be useful for you.

Each time i deployed the project (for compile the .java files too) i have to change directories paths in the .bat, but for now, this is useful for me.

Thank you.